# Testing iphone app at Client side

Tags: ios4, beta-testing

My client does not have Apple Developer account yet. What I want that I associate it with my own Dev account and let him do kind of some BEta Testing on his device. What things/steps would be required for me and him?

Thanks

Comment: Client does not need dev account to test.  You need to create what's called an [Ad Hoc Distribution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW2).  Provisioning Portal also has step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I used [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) a couple of times and I was impressed from the ease of use (Especially for clients who don't know alot about development). TestFlight simplify the process of beta testing and deployment. Much easier then using the adhoc provisioning.

The client doesn't even need to connect the device to a PC, the deployment is over the air.